# Solve the equation $x^x = 2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I was Solving this really simple looking equation $x^x = 2x$ and I know $2$ is a solution to this equation but I just couldn't reach it algebraically.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You can just use this $x^{x}-2x = 0$

Comment: $x^x$ is not algebraic, so you won't solve it using straight up algebra.

Comment: @David. Is there a definition for things which are algebraic?

Comment: See [transcendental number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number).  Note that $x^x = 2x$ can be *partially* attacked by taking the log of both sides.  This leads to $x\log(x) = \log(2) + \log(x) \implies (x - 1)\log(x) = \log(2).$  I am **not sure**, by I think that the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) was designed to help attack problems like this.  Note - I am on thin ice here; I could easily be mistaken about whether the Lambert W function is helpful here.

Comment: There is something else.  I am not the only one on thin ice here.  Normally, one might ask: how many distinct solutions are there to the equation $(x - 1)\log (x) = \log(2)$?  To the best of my knowledge, such an *issue* requires *derivatives*, which are part of Calculus (AKA Real Analysis).  Your posting is tagged, preCalculus.  To the best of my knowledge, this precludes your using derivatives to attack the *issue*.

Comment: @RounakSarkar Loosely, any sum, difference, product, quotient, composition of terms of the form $x^a$ where $a$ is a certain kind of constant. If someone were asked to solve this in an algebra course, my guess is that you are supposed to graph both functions and see where they intersect.

Comment: @DavidP. We can have a very good algebraic approximation of the root.

Comment: @user2661923, the observation that $(1/4)^{1/4}\gt2\cdot1/4$ while $(1/2)^{1/2}\lt2\cdot1/2$ shows there is at least one more solution to the equation $x^x=2x$, lying in the interval $(1/4,1/2)$. But I agree, something close to calculus seems necessary to rule out any other solutions.

Comment: @BarryCipra Nice catch.  Further, I agree that the issue of whether a function $f(x)$ is **continuous**, which seems pertinent here, may well be attacked in the preCalculus world, with $\delta,\epsilon$ proofs.  However, the original poster would then have to attack that $x^x$ is a continuous function - which may not be a walk in the park.  Then, you have the idea, which **does** require Calculus that if $f(a) < k < f(b)$, where $a < b$ and $f(x)$ is continuous in the interval $(a,b)$, then there exists a value $c$ in the interval $(a,b)$ such that $f(c) = k$.

Comment: @user2661923 The intermediate value theorem IS taught in precalculus, without proof.

Comment: $. x=2\quad x\approx 0.346323.\quad$ The first is found by inspection, the second is found by binary search where $x^{x-1}=2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making the problem more general, consider that we look for the smallest zero of the function
$$f(x)=x^x- ax \qquad \text{with} \qquad a >1$$ for which
$$f'(x)=x^x (\log (x)+1)-a$$
$$f''(x)=x^x \left(\frac{1}{x}+(\log (x)+1)^2\right)\quad > 0 \quad \forall x$$
$$f'''(x)=x^{x-2} (x (x+3)+x \log (x) (3 (x+1)+x \log (x) (\log (x)+3))-1)$$
To obtain a very first estimate, expand the function as a series centered at $x=0$; this gives
$$f(x)=1+x (\log (x)-a)+O\left(x^2\log^2(x)\right)$$ and, ignoring the higher order terms, the estimate
$$\large\color{blue}{x_0=-\frac{1}{W_{-1}\left(-e^{-a}\right)}}$$ where $W_{-1}(.)$ is the second branch of Lambert function.

We can now generate a second estimate using Newton-like method of any order $n$ (see [here](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/newton.html)). This will use the classical formulae for Newton, Halley and Householder methods.
$$x_1^{(2)}=x_0-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$$
$$x_1^{(3)}=x_0-\frac{2 f(x_0) f'(x_0)}{2 f'(x_0)^2-f(x_0) f''(x_0)}$$
$$x_1^{(4)}=x_0-\frac{3 f(x_0) \left(2 f'(x_0)^2-f(x_0) f''(x_0)\right)}{f(x_0)^2 f'''(x_0)+6 f'(x_0)^3-6 f(x_0)   f'(x_0) f''(x_0)}$$
Some numerical results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
a & x_0 & x_1^{(2)} &x_1^{(3)} & x_1^{(4)} & \text{solution} \\
 1.5 & 0.424146 & 0.466131 & 0.467197 & 0.467195 &  0.467197 \\
 2.0 & 0.317844 & 0.345912 & 0.346331 & 0.346323 &  0.346323 \\
 2.5 & 0.259916 & 0.279863 & 0.280068 & 0.280063 &  0.280064 \\
 3.0 & 0.221964 & 0.236862 & 0.236976 & 0.236973 &  0.236973 \\
 3.5 & 0.194691 & 0.206239 & 0.206307 & 0.206306 &  0.206306 \\
 4.0 & 0.173942 & 0.183151 & 0.183194 & 0.183193 &  0.183193 \\
 4.5 & 0.157526 & 0.165035 & 0.165064 & 0.165063 &  0.165063 \\
 5.0 & 0.144158 & 0.150392 & 0.150413 & 0.150412 &  0.150412 \\
 5.5 & 0.133028 & 0.138283 & 0.138298 & 0.138297 &  0.138297 \\
 6.0 & 0.123598 & 0.128084 & 0.128094 & 0.128094 &  0.128094 \\
 6.5 & 0.115493 & 0.119362 & 0.119370 & 0.119370 &  0.119370 \\
 7.0 & 0.108442 & 0.111811 & 0.111817 & 0.111817 &  0.111817 \\
 7.5 & 0.102246 & 0.105204 & 0.105208 & 0.105208 &  0.105208 \\
 8.0 & 0.096753 & 0.099369 & 0.099373 & 0.099372 &  0.099372 \\
 8.5 & 0.091847 & 0.094175 & 0.094178 & 0.094178 &  0.094178 \\
 9.0 & 0.087437 & 0.089520 & 0.089523 & 0.089522 &  0.089522 \\
 9.5  & 0.083448 & 0.085322 & 0.085324 & 0.085324 &  0.085324 \\
 10.0 & 0.079821 & 0.081516 & 0.081517 & 0.081517 &  0.081517
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

The problem is much simpler for the large root, considering that, now, we look for the zero of function
$$g(x)=x \log(x)-\log(x)-\log(a)$$
Its minimum being at $x=1$, using series and series reversion, we end with
$$x=1+t+\frac{t^2}{4}-\frac{t^3}{96}+\frac{59 t^5}{92160}-\frac{t^6}{2880}+\frac{2783
   t^7}{20643840}-\frac{t^8}{24192}+O\left(t^{9}\right)$$ where $t=\sqrt{\log(a)}$.
Again some results using this trucated series (which could be extended much further)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{series} & \text{solution} \\
 1.5 & 1.73549 &  1.73549 \\
 2.0 & 2.00000 &  2.00000 \\
 2.5 & 2.17748 &  2.17749 \\
 3.0 & 2.31128 &  2.31129 \\
 3.5 & 2.41849 &  2.41851 \\
 4.0 & 2.50777 &  2.50781 \\
 4.5 & 2.58416 &  2.58421 \\
 5.0 & 2.65082 &  2.65089 \\
 5.5 & 2.70989 &  2.70998 \\
 6.0 & 2.76289 &  2.76300 \\
 6.5 & 2.81091 &  2.81104 \\
 7.0 & 2.85478 &  2.85493 \\
 7.5 & 2.89514 &  2.89532 \\
 8.0 & 2.93250 &  2.93270 \\
 8.5 & 2.96725 &  2.96749 \\
 9.0 & 2.99974 &  3.00000 \\
 9.5 & 3.03022 &  3.03051 \\
 10.0 & 3.05892 &  3.05925
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

It does not take very high level math to show that $x^{x-1}=2$ has exactly one sution on each of $(1,\infty)$ and $(0,1)$. Getting the precise values is another matter.

In $(1,\infty)$ observe that as the base $x>1$ increases so does the positive exponent $x-1$, which guarantees that $x^{x-1}$ will be monotonically increasing. For $(0,1)$ render the function as $(1/x)^{1-x}$ (reciprocal of base, negative of exponent --> no net change in the function) and note the same trends in base and exponent as $1/x$ increases which means $x$ decreasing. Thereby $x^{x-1}$ is monotonically decreasing in $(0,1)$.

This being said, there is really no algebraic method to extract $x=2$ as the specific solution in$(1,\infty)$. We just got lucky, or you could say the problem is "rigged". The solution in $(0,1)$, given approcimately by $0.3463$, is surely irrational leaving no hope for an algebraic solution.